# NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription permission required when using ReactNative (...I think)

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

After uploading a React-Native built .ipa to the App Store, I get this upload error from Apple:

> Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Now, our app does not use any photo library functionality, and after a global search the only library I can see which uses the `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` is the `CameraRoll` component in React-Native.

I'm assuming this error is being trigged by simply incuding RN, even though no CameraRoll is actually used. Is this correct to assume?

If not, is there a way I can check if any third party dependency does?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add,

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>your description here</string>
```

into your `info.plist`

Comment: Wasn't my question. I'm asking if using RN out of the box means you need to define this permission even if you're NOT using the CameraRoll component

Comment: no if you are not using camera roll then you are not require but check twice that you are using it somewhere!